# i want to crop a .tif format image using php

Tags: php, crop

i want to crop a .tif format image using php .
i have done if image is in .jpg , gif or png format but i want to crop a .tif image with certain dimensions i.e from 200x200 right from a full image of 1024x1024.please consider it is .tif format .

http://rkwebsolutions.in.md-16.webhostbox.net/check/8713855051.tif

i use this function for jpeg/png/gif format image but unable to crop a .tif image

```
function cropImage($source_image, $target_image, $crop_area)
{
    // detect source image type from extension
    $source_file_name = basename($source_image);
    $source_image_type = substr($source_file_name, -3, 3);

    // create an image resource from the source image  
    switch(strtolower($source_image_type))
    {
        case 'jpg':
            $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            break;

        case 'gif':
            $original_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
            break;

        case 'png':
            $original_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            break;    

        default:
            trigger_error('cropImage(): Invalid source image type', E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
    }

    // create a blank image having the same width and height as the crop area
    // this will be our cropped image
    $cropped_image = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_area['width'], $crop_area['height']);

    // copy the crop area from the source image to the blank image created above
    imagecopy($cropped_image, $original_image, 0, 0, $crop_area['left'], $crop_area['top'], 
              $crop_area['width'], $crop_area['height']);

    // detect target image type from extension
    $target_file_name = basename($target_image);
    $target_image_type = substr($target_file_name, -3, 3);

    // save the cropped image to disk
    switch(strtolower($target_image_type))
    {
        case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($cropped_image, $target_image, 100);
            break;

        case 'gif':
            imagegif($cropped_image, $target_image);
            break;

        case 'png':
            imagepng($cropped_image, $target_image, 0);
            break;    

        default:
            trigger_error('cropImage(): Invalid target image type', E_USER_ERROR);
            imagedestroy($cropped_image);
            imagedestroy($original_image);
            return false;
    }

    // free resources
    imagedestroy($cropped_image);
    imagedestroy($original_image);

    return true;
}


// using the function to crop an image
$source_image = 'image.jpg';
$target_image = 'cropped_image.jpg';
$crop_area = array('top' => 100, 'left' => 100, 'height' => 300, 'width' => 300);

cropImage($source_image, $target_image, $crop_area);
```

can anyone help 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to jpg first than resize. Example code if You have imagemagic installed on Your server:

```
exec("convert /path/to/file.tiff /path/to/file.jpg", $err);
```

Comment: will it not be possible to resize it without converting to jpg ?.

Comment: Maybe there is way to resize without converting. After resize You can still do reconvert from resized jpg to tiff if You want

Comment: i tried converting a image but seems image imagemagic  not installed on my server can you please guide .

Comment: to check if imagick is installed watch for section imagick in phpinfo()

Comment: And if you want to install it there is a lot of tutorials about that in the web.

Comment: thanks for all your responses i'm running win7 can you please guide how can i configure it on my local server and another i want to upload zip folder that is having 1000's of images i want to upload all the images in  zip folder in once and crop any idea . thanks in advance

Comment: There is a lot articles how to do it look here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=install+imagemagick+on+local+server or here https://www.google.pl/#hl=pl&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=FOfVpZCpJoXU6KQwLAbrww&pq=installing%20imagemagick%20on%20windows%207%20local%20server&cp=19&gs_id=85&xhr=t&q=imagemagick+install+windows+7+local+server&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=imagemagick+install+windows+7+local+server&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46471029,d.Yms&fp=dbcd7fcecfd12cd1&biw=1280&bih=923&bs=1 I believe you will find how to do it.